# HTML+CSS One position class for different size icon sprites

Tags: html, css, hover, position, sprite

Trying to make a menu with icons that change color on hover. The point is: having inline-css on each menu icon to change the sprite file, for example:  `<a href="#" style="background-image: url(menuSprites/smartphone.png);" class="">Contact</a>` and in the CSS - only one class:

```
.menuPicHeader a{   
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 50px;
        background-position: X X;
    }

    .menuPicHeader a:hover{
            background-position: X -X;
    }
```

The problem - each icon pair (2 icons per sprite, 1 normal 1 hover) is different size  . So if I pre-set some background-position offset, it obviously doesn't work because of the different sizes. Is there some tool/easy method for making sprites that would work with the same offset? This is what I used to test it, made it with one generator using 50 pixel vetical gap:

(phone and the ball - different sizes)

File 1:

[image]

File2 :

[image]

P.S. Generator I used: http://www.cssportal.com/css-sprite-generator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make the images the same size for each image (better) or set special properties for individuals.

Comment: I make both of the files the same size, place the 2 icons in the same corners with the same distance, and it still doesn't align.

Comment: Well you don't want them in the corners. You want them on center.